When making a batch cocktail how do I preserve the carbonation
I am making a large batch of Apple Cider Bellinis for a party the recipe calls for:

1 gallon of Apple cider
2 bottles of Prosecco
1 cup of Spiced rum
1/2 cup of Apple pie liqueur

I am afraid that the Prosecco will go flat too soon. Is there a way to preserve the carbonation?

Make smaller batches.
Instead of opening both bottles of prosecco and have them both start to go flat at the start of the party, use one bottle to make half a batch, and make the other half once it runs out.

Most cocktails with a carbonated component require to top up with that component to keep the carbonation. So, make a batch of all non carbonated components, in a jar with a tap, tap the mix into the glasses, then only top up with the prosecco just before serving.

You could funnel your cocktail into several clean, empty plastic cola bottles, and seal them until needed. You can then open them one at a time during the party.

Find a local homebrewer that does counter-pressure bottle filling to do the bottling for you.  May even be able to sweet talk and/or pay for kegging the Bellinis to serve on-tap at the party  ;-)
Be aware that there's a risk of over-carbonation if fermentation starts in bottles so, for just bottling for one event, consume any leftover bottles as soon as practicable and keep bottles cold.  If you really screw up, bottles could explode.
If you fill bottles, to minimize carbonation loss:
Everything should be cold so, 1) chill all ingredients well before mixing a bulk batch of the cocktail mix then bottle right away and 2) chill bottles and other stuff that the mix touches when filling.
Fill bottles using a siphon.  Tips: Use clear tygon type 1/4" ID plastic tubing.  Fill slowly- slower flow = less carbonation loss,.  Control flow by raising or lowering bottle relative to level of in cocktail container.  Judge carbornation loss by amount of bubbling as bottle fills.  Fill the bottles with end of tubing just above the bottom of the bottle and a low flow- can increase as bottle fills.  Fill to the top of the bottle- the level will reduce as tubing is removed- the air space is a good thing.  To stop flow, crimp tubing tightly or, better, use a "plastic tubing pinch clamp".   Prep for a bit of drippage from the end of the tubing.   Secure the tubing to the cocktail container so the tubing's end is close to the bottom of the mix container.
If you want something impressive, there are insulated "pressurized growlers" which will serve on-tap like draft beer.  A nice but costly (on mfg's site so shop around):  GrowlerWerks' uKeg.  The uKeg Pro manual has instructions  for sparkling wines and includes two recipes.   The cheaper Go model might work- it only has 7 and 15 PSIG settings while the Pro is adjustable 0-15 PSIG.  There are other brands of pressurized growlers but make sure they use nonproprietary 8 and/or 16 gram CO2 cartridges and be sure to buy cartridges with food grade CO2.
